# Snort looking for incorrect rules directory

Tags: snort, fedora-23

I am in the middle of setting ups snort for the first time on Fedora 23. I have configured pulledpork for auto rules download. As you can see from the picture below, the test to see if pulledpork has worked tries to manually run Snort, which gives me the below error, as it looks for `/etc/snort//etc/snort/rules/local.rules` which clearly doesn't exist. I have looked in snort.conf and I can see a line that says `include $RULE_PATH/local.rules` which I thought may be the issue, but the `var` for `$Rule_PATH` is what it's supposed to be, `/etc/snort/rules`

I have no idea what else could be causing this. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

changed RULE_PATH to rules and it's ok now.